# How can I insert an image map into a Wordpress blog post?

Tags: images, html

I'm trying to insert a custom image map into a blog post, so that clicking on different parts of an image at the top of the post will lead to anchors in other parts of the post.

I have generated the image map code correctly, and tested it in a separate non-wordpress plain HTML page, where it worked fine.

Whenever I insert the HTML (using the code view, not the WYSIWYG editor view), it gets erased as soon as I save the post. However, I checked and it looks like `<map>` and `<area>` are both [permitted tags on Wordpres.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/).

This blog is not hosted by Wordpress.com (it's actually a site on the WPMU instane hosted [right here on Stack Exchange](http://blogoverflow.com/)), but I would assume that by default, the downloaded version of Wordpress would allow at *least* the same tags as the Wordpress.com hosted blogs.

Is there a setting which a network super-admin has to change to allow these tags, or am I inserting them incorrectly? If the tags are allowed, what might cause them to be outright removed?

Comment: You should make this an template file.

Comment: What do you mean @kaiser? I am not a blog admin, so I can't edit the templates. I don't see any reason to put it in the template though; it's only for use on a single post.

Comment: Without _real_ access, you can't achieve it. Anyway: Even if it's only used 1&times;, you should use a template.

Comment: @kaiser - I believe he wants just to insert an image map to a post ..

Comment: Yes, but without the possibility to allow those tags: No Chance.

Comment: I would prefer a solution that uses a shortcode over using templates, but you still need admin access. The idea would be to paste the code in a custom field and have a shortcode that just prints the custom field's content.

Comment: I can ask an admin to change settings or add things if necessary, I just can't do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it should achievable like this  ..

```
<div>

<img class="alignnone" id="imageMaps" src="http://businessplumbing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Sloan-Royal-Flushometer.png" alt="" width="298" height="595" usemap="#flushometer" border="0" />

<map name="flushometer" id="flushometer"> 

<area shape="rect" coords="219,6,277,41" href="http://businessplumbing.com/products-page/lavatory-sink/sloan-royal-flushometer-a-72-cp-cover/" alt="A-72 CP Cover" />

<area shape="rect" coords="218,42,278,70" href="http://businessplumbing.com/products-page/lavatory-sink/sloan-royal-flushometer-a-71-inside-cover/" alt="A-71 Inside Cover" />

</map>

</div>
```

copy the whole code (including div) and paste in HTML tab in editor .
the top 2 "covers" on this drawing should work as different links.

Comment: Did you visit the link the OP provided with the allowed tags?

Comment: `img`, `map` and `area` are all allowed codes, and I put in code very much like that above. That's why I'm confused. Why didn't it work?

Comment: @kaiser- Yes, I did visited, and they seem to be allowed as also the poster claims . There is a reason for why I have posted the code and asked to copy&paste as is , and post the results back in order facilitate troubleshooting..

Comment: @krembo99 - thanks , Although I myself am not the original question owner - your answered helped - for some reason I previously could not post an image map - but copying your code worked . I do not know why, maybe it is the <div> part . Anyhow - thanks a lot ..